# Adapt dynamodb golang interface and client to add date querying function

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I've implemented dynamodb interface and db client to do some specific queries, right now i want to query database with date filtering with given range, but i dont know how to modift those interfaces:

this is my dynamodb client:

```
package dynamo

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"

    
)

type API interface {
    DescribeTable(context.Context, *dynamodb.DescribeTableInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.DescribeTableOutput, error)
    GetItem(context.Context, *dynamodb.GetItemInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error)
    Query(context.Context, *dynamodb.QueryInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.QueryOutput, error)
    PutItem(context.Context, *dynamodb.PutItemInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.PutItemOutput, error)
    DeleteItem(context.Context, *dynamodb.DeleteItemInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.DeleteItemOutput, error)
    UpdateItem(context.Context, *dynamodb.UpdateItemInput, ...func(*dynamodb.Options)) (*dynamodb.UpdateItemOutput, error)
}

// NewClient creates a Client based on a DynamoDB table
func NewClient(table string, svc API) Client {
    return Client{
        tableName: table,
        svc:       svc,
    }
}

// Client represent a dynamoDB client
type Client struct {
    tableName string
    svc       API
}

// Ping checks if the database connection is working and the table exists
func (dbClient Client) Ping(ctx context.Context) error {
    result, err := dbClient.svc.DescribeTable(ctx, &dynamodb.DescribeTableInput{TableName: dbClient.TableName()})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if result == nil {
        return ErrNotFound
    }

    return nil
}

// TableName returns the table name
func (dbClient Client) TableName() *string { return aws.String(dbClient.tableName) }

// API returns the interface of the DynamoDB API
func (dbClient Client) API() API { return dbClient.svc }

// Get performs a read on the repository based on the given key
// it returns an error if the item does not exist
func (dbClient Client) Get(ctx context.Context, keyFilter db.Condition, item interface{}) error {
    result, err := dbClient.svc.GetItem(ctx,
        &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
            TableName:      dbClient.TableName(),
            Key:            getKey(keyFilter),
            ConsistentRead: aws.Bool(true),
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling GetItem: %s", err)
    }

    if result.Item == nil {
        return ErrNotFound
    }

    err = attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, item)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal Record, %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}

// Query performs a read o the repository returning multiple items
func (dbClient Client) Query(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition db.Condition, items interface{}) error {
    return dbClient.query(ctx, keyCondition, filterCondition, items, nil, aws.Bool(true))
}

// QueryIndex performs a read o the repository returning multiple items
func (dbClient Client) QueryIndex(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition db.Condition, indexName string, items interface{}) error {
    return dbClient.query(ctx, keyCondition, filterCondition, items, aws.String(indexName), nil)
}

// Create creates the given item on the repository
func (dbClient Client) Create(ctx context.Context, item interface{}) error {
    attributeValues, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(item)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error marshaling new item: %s", err)
    }

    _, err = dbClient.svc.PutItem(ctx,
        &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
            Item:      attributeValues,
            TableName: dbClient.TableName(),
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling PutItem: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}

// Delete removes the items according to the given filter
func (dbClient Client) Delete(ctx context.Context, filter db.Condition) error {

    _, err := dbClient.svc.DeleteItem(ctx,
        &dynamodb.DeleteItemInput{
            Key:       getKey(filter),
            TableName: dbClient.TableName(),
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling DeleteItem: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}

// Update updates the item with the given filter
func (dbClient Client) Update(
    ctx context.Context,
    filter db.Condition,
    expr expression.Expression,
    item interface{},
) error {

    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
        Key:                       getKey(filter),
        TableName:                 dbClient.TableName(),
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        UpdateExpression:          expr.Update(),
        ReturnValues:              types.ReturnValueAllNew,
    }

    out, err := dbClient.svc.UpdateItem(ctx, input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(out.Attributes, item)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal Record, %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func (dbClient Client) query(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition db.Condition, items interface{}, indexName *string, consistentRead *bool) error {
    var keyCondBuilder expression.KeyConditionBuilder
    keyCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}) {
        if keyCondBuilder.IsSet() {
            keyCondBuilder = keyCondBuilder.And(expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value)))
        } else {
            keyCondBuilder = expression.Key(key).Equal(expression.Value(value))
        }
    })

    builder := expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(keyCondBuilder)

    var filterCondBuilder expression.ConditionBuilder
    if filterCondition != nil {
        filterCondition.ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}) {
            if filterCondBuilder.IsSet() {
                filterCondBuilder = filterCondBuilder.And(expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value)))
            } else {
                filterCondBuilder = expression.Name(key).Equal(expression.Value(value))
            }
        })
        builder = builder.WithFilter(filterCondBuilder)
    }

    expr, err := builder.Build()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error when building expression: %v", err)
    }

    params := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
        TableName:                 dbClient.TableName(),
        IndexName:                 indexName,
        ConsistentRead:            consistentRead,
    }

    result, err := dbClient.svc.Query(ctx, params)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error calling Query: %s", err)
    }

    err = attributevalue.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, items)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("got error unmarshalling: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

and this interface for client:

```
package db

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression"
)

// Client represent a generic Database client interface
type Client interface {
    Get(ctx context.Context, filter Condition, item interface{}) error
    Query(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition Condition, items interface{}) error
    QueryIndex(ctx context.Context, keyCondition, filterCondition Condition, indexName string, items interface{}) error
    Create(ctx context.Context, item interface{}) error
    Delete(ctx context.Context, filter Condition) error
    Update(ctx context.Context, filter Condition, expr expression.Expression, item interface{}) error
}

// Condition creates a filter to search into database
type Condition interface {
    Add(key string, value interface{}) Condition
    ForEach(func(key string, value interface{}))
}

type condition map[string]interface{}

// NewCondition returns a Condition
func NewCondition() Condition {
    return make(condition)
}

// Add adds a new couple key value to filter
func (f condition) Add(key string, value interface{}) Condition {
    f[key] = value
    return f
}

// ForEach executes the given function for each couple key value
func (f condition) ForEach(fun func(key string, value interface{})) {
    for k, v := range f {
        fun(k, v)
    }
}
```

i want to do this query by modifying my interface

```
    input := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        IndexName:              aws.String("created-at-index"),
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("created_at BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime"),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            ":startTime": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: startTime.Format(time.RFC3339)},
            ":endTime":   &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: endTime.Format(time.RFC3339)},
        },
    }
```